# What does lowercase t means in ps state code

Tags: linux, ps

When I run `ps xaf` I have a following output:

[image: ps xaf result]

So my application has state code `t+`. But I can't find what it means. In `man ps` where is no such state code:

[image: man ps]

Does it equal to uppercase `T` state code? If it is, why do I always only get `T` state code when I do `kill -SIGSTOP <pid>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all versions of Linux know about the `t` code. It was introduced in 2.6.33 as *tracing stop* that is different from signal stop indicated by `T`. In the latest versions of `proc(5)` (2014-07-10 or later) you will find the following:

```
                    T  Stopped (on a signal) or (before Linux 2.6.33)
                       trace stopped
                    t  Tracing stop (Linux 2.6.33 onward)
                    W  Paging (only before Linux 2.6.0)
                    X  Dead (from Linux 2.6.0 onward)
                    x  Dead (Linux 2.6.33 to 3.13 only)
                    K  Wakekill (Linux 2.6.33 to 3.13 only)
                    W  Waking (Linux 2.6.33 to 3.13 only)
                    P  Parked (Linux 3.9 to 3.13 only)
```

In addition to the usual R,S,D,Z,T,W status codes.

See the latest version on [Michael Kerrisk page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

Answer (score 4):

According to `task_state_array[]` from kernel sources 't' translates into "tracing stop", while 'T' is just "stopped".

```
/*
 * The task state array is a strange "bitmap" of
 * reasons to sleep. Thus "running" is zero, and
 * you can test for combinations of others with
 * simple bit tests.
 */
static const char * const task_state_array[] = {
    "R (running)",      /*   0 */
    "S (sleeping)",     /*   1 */
    "D (disk sleep)",   /*   2 */
    "T (stopped)",      /*   4 */
    "t (tracing stop)", /*   8 */
    "X (dead)",     /*  16 */
    "Z (zombie)",       /*  32 */
};
```

Comment: Have a look to: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/eae21770b4fed5597623aad0d618190fa60426ff/fs/proc/array.c#L120